# Method/Property that will be only accessible when run in xunit

Tags: .net-core, xunit

In .net core, how can i define a method/property that will be only accessible through unit tests(xuint)? I am fine with it throwing an exception when it gets accessed by code that is not run during a unit test

Comment: Do the names of your test methods have any characteristic that would distinguish them as test methods?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is a really odd requirement, could you explain why you want to do this? It sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Method/Property can not be accessible in xunit unless you are writing a library which xunit using. But if you mean that methods should be accessible only from the test library, then you should reconsider what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to expose some private members for testing purpose? If so, then don't do that, but test behavior against public methods/properties.